# Detect the scrolling to bottom of the page using Dart

Tags: dart

I could detect scroll reaches to bottom by using Javascript

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
        // when scroll to bottom of the page
    }
});
```

But I cannot find document.height in Dart.
How can I get height of document and compare with window.scrollY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, although I always had trouble understanding the various heights, that `document.body.clientHeight` should work (i.e. I have used it once)

```
_updateScrollInfo([_]) {
  if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.clientHeight) {
    print("at bottom");
  }
}
window.onScroll.listen(_updateScrollInfo);
```

DartPad example: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/6fcfb715e4090a1aafe4

Comment: I am running into a strange problem where my `dart:html` project does not exhibit the typical values for window.innerHeight, window.scrollY, and document.body.clientHeight. Mine is `1070 | 0 | 1070` at the top and `1070 | 550 | 1070` at the bottom. I am totally stumped.